# Use ngx-translate in Ionic 2 : how to add downloaded external languages files ? dynamically change folder of json or use setTranslate?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ngx-translate

I use nxg-translate in Ionic 2 project.

in my `app.module.ts`, i use `translateHttpLoader` :

```
...
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicImageViewerModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, AppOptions),
    IonicAudioModule.forRoot(),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
           deps: [Http]
        }
    })
  ],
...


export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http,) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, 'assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

In my app, i have to download lang files from a external zip, because the client want to have the possibility to change traductions without to republish app, and languages files contains specific elements which could change (markers for a map, etc..)

So i download and unzip files, 
and when i have the json content of the lang (=`data`), i add it to the translation tools with `setTranslate` method.

`this.translate.setTranslation(lang,data);`

But when i check if the language is well added with the getTranslation method, i have an error because it does not find the file. (http request error). It is normal, my folder `assets/i18n/` is empty, 
but with the `setTranslation` method, i think that i should normally find what i had added juste before ? Or I do not use the module as expected ?

I have tried to put an empty file in assets/in18n folder (for example fr.json), to see if it could work, but it does not change anything.

If i change the url of folder in translateHttpLoader, to have exact downloaded zip content folder, it works, but the problem is that i would be able to change in function of platform (ios/android), because folder of zip is not the same in function of the OS.

**My question is:**
- could i change the folder of assets in function of platform, in my `createTranslateLoader` function  (or after app is initialized)
- how work  setTranslation method : does it need a minimal file in `i18n` folder to work ?
- have you an idea to improve my use of ngx-translate ?

thanks !

David

Answer (score 0):

//I have tried to put an empty file in assets/in18n folder (for example fr.json), to see if it could work, but it does not change anything.//

if you had same architecture

```
| src 
   | app
   | assets
      | i18n
         | fr.json
         | en.json
```

Could you try with the below code

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: Http,) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

By default, there is no loader available. You can add translations manually using `setTranslation` but it is better to use a loader.
You can write your own loader, or import an existing one.